# Codeigniter group by if a field is not null only

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have the following query:

```
$this->db->select('SUM(cost_price) AS cost_price,SUM(cost_price) AS total,employees.username AS staff_name');
        $this->db->from('items');
        $this->db->join('customers', 'customers.person_id = items.customer_id');
        $this->db->join('employees', 'employees.person_id = items.staff_id');
        $this->db->join('people', 'people.person_id = customers.person_id');
 $this->db->group_by('items.is_serialized');
```

In the items table I have a field called is_serialized, I want to group all rows having a value in the is_serialized    field but not group if the row is NULL, would it be possible to do so using my query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use "CASE" function in group by clause to check for not null values only.

Eg:

```
 $this->db->group_by("CASE WHEN items.is_serialized IS NOT NULL THEN items.is_serialized END",FALSE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put below where condition to be group by is_serialized

```
$this->db->where('items.is_serialized IS NOT NULL');
```

Comment: I need the is_serialized NULL rows too in the result.

Comment: Would you please share columns of each table (table structure of all tables) and which field should not be null?